# What is ORACLE_SID , Why it is USED

Tags: oracle

I am totally new to oracle. I have seen somebody use to set oracle_sid before login.

But don't know what is the purpose of Oracle_sid .

Comment: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORACLE_SID

Comment: The Oracle System ID (SID) is used to uniquely identify a particular database on a system.

Comment: is it necessary to create oracle_sid before login .

Comment: Just had to start dealing with Oracle products and working with them is often almost like acting as an archeologist. After 6 years, there is still no good answer to what this environment variable is, why it must exist and what it's value must be. Even the official documentation just refers to it without any explanation.

Answer (score 2):

ORACLE_SID is instance. An instance is a background processes that processes or operates a database.

Comment: this is not an answer